# how to use IClaimsTransformation in core2.2 mvc project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

I am trying to learn how to use `IClaimsTransformation` to modify users claims in windows authentication. But when I try to use it I get an error saying

> "InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found."

I am mainly trying it on mac but also I tried in my company pc in company domain. Both of them gives me the same error. Also I am IIS express (debug mode from both VS and Rider).

in my startup file

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        services.AddSingleton<IClaimsTransformation, UserClaims>();

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });



    }
```

and I have this class for claims transformation

```
public class UserClaims: IClaimsTransformation
{
    public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        var ci = (ClaimsIdentity) principal.Identity;
        var c = new Claim(ci.RoleClaimType, "Admin");
        ci.AddClaim(c);
        return Task.FromResult(principal);
    }
}
```

also using this decorator for my controller

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all using Rider as an IDE messed up my debug settings and after deleting the demo app and restoring the debug settings to default IIS Express settings I managed to get my code working.

After that I had an 403 error every time I tried to debug my application and with the help of @itminus we found the the problem in my middlewares order. I was using UseAuthorization() over the UseAuthentication() and that was my mistake. So putting UseAuthentication() over the UseAuthorization() solved my second problem.

Answer (score 0):

> "InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found."

I got the same issue when I used Windows Authentication several months ago. It turns out I didn't enable the `Windows Authentication`.

Please check the Properties/Debug tab, and make sure the `Enable Windows Authentication` is checked:

[image]

---

As a side note, you're modifying the **original** `principal`. IMO, returning a **brand new** principal is preferred:

```
public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
{
    var cp = principal.Clone();                   // create a copy
    var ci = (ClaimsIdentity)cp.Identity;
    var c = new Claim(ci.RoleClaimType, "Admin");
    ci.AddClaim(c);                               // modify the copy
    return Task.FromResult(cp);                          
}
```

Comment: Windows Authentication is already enabled, but there was a problem with my IISEsxpress settings. When I reset them it started to work. But this time I cannot debug my ClaimsTransformation class, it does not stop at my breakpoints.

For the returning original principal you are right it is better to return new one but it is a demo code for the testing propose so I didnt think on it to much :)

Comment: @MustafaYılmaz "but there was a problem with my IISEsxpress settings": If that's the case, it's better to post it as an answer.

Comment: It is actually half of the answer. I still cannot use my IClaimsTransformation. My problem is if I use [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] it does not run my claimstransformation class but if I use [Authorize] my transformation runs successfully.

Comment: @MustafaYılmaz 1. I tested your code yesterday. It works pretty fine for me except that  I have to clone the principal due to a privilledge issue.  2. Since you've changed the IIS Settings, it's better to show us what settings are changed , it would be nice if you tell us more about the error info/ the behavior. Also a way to reproduce this issue is preferred.

Comment: I am using directly VS debug with IIS Express and just used restore to defaults to reset the IIS Express settings. As for the code I uploaded it to github maybe that way it will be easier to talk about it. My problem is when I try to debug the claimstransformer class to check what is going on my code does not stop on my breakpoint and directly gives an 403 error to me if I use [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]. But if I use only [Authorize] on my controller my code stops on my breakpoint on my class. https://github.com/RaistlinMY/ClaimsTransformerTest

Comment: @MustafaYılmaz That's because you're using ASP.NET 3.0 (instead of 2.2 described in OP) , the ASP.NET Core 3.0 employs a `UseAuthorization()` middleware and you invoke that middleware too early before `UseAuthentication()`.

Comment: @MustafaYılmaz Also, I doubt whether you said "a problem with my IISEsxpress settings" means this [settings](https://github.com/RaistlinMY/ClaimsTransformerTest/blob/1b5204aa909bba42ea114868a563179de14ee30d/WebApplication/Properties/launchSettings.json#L3-L4). If that's the cause, your changing is exactly what I did in VS. See [Official docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#launch-settings-debugger) : `Alternatively, the properties can be configured in the iisSettings node of the launchSettings.json file:`

Comment: you are the best @itminus :) I am fairly new to the .Net MVC and I was sure I am missing something very basic somewhere. Putting UseAuthentication() over the UseAuthorization() worked. As for using core3.0 I was playing around this code over different PCs and the last one has only 3.0 so I used it, didn't think it will cause any other problem for me. Thanks for the help and everything.